# How to increase external margin in a gnuplot multiplot to fit a larger title font?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a multiplot and I want to increase the title font size.

When I try:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set terminal png size 1024, 1024
set output 'tmp.png'
set multiplot layout 2,2 title "Asdf Qwer" font ",30"
plot sin(x)
plot cos(x)
plot exp(x)
plot exp(-x)
```

the title becomes too large and gets cut off:

[image]

I tried to increase the top margin with `tmargin` (here at an exaggerated value for demonstration):

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set tmargin 30
set terminal png size 1024, 1024
set output 'tmp.png'
set multiplot layout 2,2 title "Asdf Qwer" font ",30"
plot sin(x)
plot cos(x)
plot exp(x)
plot exp(-x)
```

but that only increases the internal margin above of each plot, and the top title is still cut off:

[image]

Tested in gnuplot 5.2 patchlevel 6, Ubuntu 19.04.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, something goes wrong with calculating the space for the title. So, instead, one possibility would be setting the margin manually and adding the title as label.

**Code:**

```
### multiplot title with enough space
reset session

set multiplot layout 2,2 margin 0.1,0.95,0.1,0.85 spacing 0.1,0.1
set label 1 "Asdf Qwer" center font ",40" at screen 0.5, 0.95

plot sin(x)
plot cos(x)
plot exp(x)
plot exp(-x)

unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Ah, so labels do take up space correctly automatically. Then the title does feel buggy.

Comment: You set the position of the label `at screen 0.5,0.95` or wherever you want. If for example a title with `font ",50"` would stick out of the graph, then you have to set a larger margin for multiplot and also lower the position of the label. All manually :-(. Yes, multiplot title looks buggy to me.

Answer (score 1):

Gnuplot sometimes has problems in correctly estimating space needed for text.

A simple workaround would be to create a two-line header with an empty first line (`\n`):

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set terminal png size 1024, 1024
set output 'tmp.png'
set multiplot layout 2,2 title "\nAsdf Qwer" font ",30"
plot sin(x)
plot cos(x)
plot exp(x)
plot exp(-x)
unset multiplot
```

Result:
[image: title with empty first line]

Another possibility would be to exchange the png terminal by the pngcairo terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env gnuplot
set terminal pngcairo size 1024, 1024
set output 'tmp.png'
set multiplot layout 2,2 title "Asdf Qwer" font ",30"
plot sin(x)
plot cos(x)
plot exp(x)
plot exp(-x)
unset multiplot
```

Result:
[image: pngcairo terminal]